# How do I fight the 3rd to last opponent in the Colosseum?

Tags: yakuza-0

I have fought every opponent at the Bed of Styx colosseum except for one. Even after repeating every tournament multiple times, I haven't met the third to last person in the opponent list.

Is there something specific I need to do before I can fight this opponent? Or am I just getting extremely unlucky?

[image: Opponent list with third to last box hidden]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The opponent you are missing in the Bed of Styx has a condition that must be met ***outside of the minigame*** in order to appear. I recommend going and taking a look at any other content you might be missing, or I've listed the fighter in the spoiler box below if you want to know right now

> The fighter you are missing is Sotaro Komaki, the trainer who teaches Majima new fighting moves. He should join the Bed of Styx after learning all available moves, and can be found in the Hangman Romp and the Devil Circus